# How to draw a line with an arrow?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I have the following code, that draws a line with a (very) small arrow...

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);
    p.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor;

    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 10, 10, 100, 100);
    p.Dispose();
}
```

I want to draw a **big** arrow (*circle, square, triangle* etc...), **keeping the same line width**.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'd want to use a `CustomLineCap` with a `GraphicsPath`. Here's an example:

```
using(Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black))
using(GraphicsPath capPath = new GraphicsPath())
{
    // A triangle
    capPath.AddLine(-20, 0, 20, 0);
    capPath.AddLine(-20, 0, 0, 20);
    capPath.AddLine(0, 20, 20, 0);

    p.CustomEndCap = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CustomLineCap(null, capPath);

    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 0, 50, 100, 50);
}
```

You want to "design" your cap with a line going top-to-bottom and from (0, 0) to get the correct coordinates.

**EDIT**: I just wanted to mention that you can also use `AdjustableArrowCap` to draw an arrow of a specific size and fill it but because you mentioned the requirement for other shapes, I've used a CustomLineCap.

Comment: yeah.. I know about customcap... the inconvenient is that it will not change with the line width... ideally for me if the cap was a property like "CapScale" or "CapSize"... but it does not exist... It also a pity that does not exist a `AdjustableCircleCap` or `AdjustableSquareCap`...

Comment: @serhio - What do you mean it won't change with the line width? If you change the pen width, it will draw a thicker line. Could you explain more what you mean? You could also roll your *own* `AdjustableCircleCap`, it's not hard when you know how to use the `GraphicsPath` properly. If you're not sure, I can write one up for you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-a-line-with-line-caps

Answer (score 2):

As [TheCloudlessSky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3392619/171846) mentioned, `AdjustableArrowCap` can be used to draw the arrow head.

```
public static void DrawLine(Graphics g, Point from, Point to)
{
    var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);

    pen.CustomEndCap = new AdjustableArrowCap(5, 5);

    g.DrawLine(pen, from, to);
}
```